# Error level is not returning correctly when executing in sqlcmd

Tags: vb.net, sqlcmd

When I run my code directly in cmd.exe, I can return an error level of 1, but when it comes to my VB.NET form in which cmd.exe is called, the error level is 0. This is my code:

```
Dim strCmdText1
strCmdText1 = "/C sqlcmd -S CD05\SQLEXPRESS2005 -E -b -d AUTO_UPDATION -i H:\Temp1\537-2.sql -o H:\Temp1\Result.txt |  @echo %%ERRORLEVEL%%>H:\Temp1\errorlevel.txt "
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText1)
```

Is there any mistake in joining 2 commands in `strCmdtext1`?

Comment: Try with a configured Process: `Dim proc As Process = New Process() proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe" proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "Your Command Line Without the Errorlevel Part" proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False proc.Start() proc.WaitForExit() Dim errorlevel = proc.ExitCode proc.Dispose()`

Comment: Here I want to actually return the error level,so that I can display the error message. ie, if it is 1 i can read the output message and display them.Otherwise there is no need of displaying the output messages.And also I don't want to use process here.Please help me out.It works on my above code when it is executed directly on cmd.exe but don't through my vb.net form.

Comment: There are no messages shown anywhere in the code you see in the previous comment. `proc.ExitCode` returns the ErrorLevel, here. If you want to show the Error message, redirect StandardError. Also, you are using the Process class in your code.